# First position in google search

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using WebView and  URL link, for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=blue I would like to open the first position in google search for this query. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append &btnI after the URL.  So in your case it will be
https://www.google.com/search?q=blue&btnI